# Data Archival Strategy for CRM system

Tags: crm, archive

I need to archive data from a CRM system. Does anyone have any idea on how this can be achieved and what are possible strategies for the archiving?

Comment: What CRM are you using?  Start by investigating any inbuilt archiving functionality.

Comment: Hi @Ram which CRM system you are using. I also need help for same. I need the archiving things in salesforce. Please suggest if you have any idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the archival functionality in the CRM itself.